# Why is my Java short getting filled with 1s with an unsigned right shift?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

When I execute an unsigned right shift as follows:

```java
short value = (short)0b1111111111100000;
System.out.println(wordToString(value));
value >>>= 5;
```

I get `1111111111111111`.
So, the value is shifted right, but filled with 1s, which seems to be the same behavior as `>>`

However, I was expecting it to fill with 0s regardless of sign, yielding the following:
`0000011111111111`

Here is a relevant REPL to play with my code: https://repl.it/@spmcbride1201/shift-rotate

Comment: Like C (and C++), Java promotes smaller integer types (`byte char short`) to `int` before doing any compuation on them. `(short)0xffe0` promotes to `(int)0xffffffe0` which is right shifted to `0x07ffffff` and then truncated to `0xffff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you're getting has to do with the fact that `short`s are promoted to `int`s before applying the shift operation. In fact, if you assign the result of the shift operator to a `int` variable you get the expected result:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    short value = (short)0b1111111111100000;
    System.out.println(value); //-32, which is the given number
    int result = value >>> 5;
    System.out.println(result); //134217727, which is 00000111111111111111111111111111

  }
```

If you assign the result to a `short`, you only get the lower bits.

This is due to the fact that the bytecode language doesn't really deal with any types smaller than `int`.